# How to subset data based on ratios between values in multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I have a set of data with 50K records of users (by email) and I need to choose only 10K of those records, by a predefined ratio of values in each category: Region, Role and Position.

For example, if I have the following sample of data (11 rows) how can I subset it to get 5 rows, split the following way:
    - 80% AMER, 20% INDIA
    - For each Role have 60% Sales and the rest would be at random
    - For Position, get a split of 20% being Managers and 80% being Operational

```
Email             Geo    Role       Position
abs@example.com   AMER   Sales      Manager
sdf@example.com   AMER   Sales      Operational
dsfe@example.com  EMEA   Sales      Manager
sdw@example.com   AMER   Sales      Operational
aydje@example.com EMEA   Sales      Manager
fdsed@example.com AMER   Testing    Operational
Sfe@example.com   AMER   Testing    Manager
dfgt@example.com  INDIA  Testing    Manager
gsdr@example.com  INDIA  Testing    Operational
dmgru@example.com AMER   Marketing  Operational
edr@example.com   INDIA  Marketing  Operational
```

I expect to get something like this:

```
Email             Geo    Role       Position
abs@example.com   AMER   Sales      Manager
sdf@example.com   AMER   Sales      Operational
sdw@example.com   AMER   Sales      Operational
fdsed@example.com AMER   Testing    Operational
edr@example.com   INDIA  Marketing  Operational
```

I'm aware that there will be more than one right solution, especially with more data, but any one is fine, as long as the predefined ratios are respected.